# Nvidia driver (355) increase 10 degrees to CPU of Lenovo Z40-70

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, temperature

I have a Lenovo z40-70 with nvidia geforce 820, when I run nouveau drivers the temperature is near of 36 degrees but when I install any Nvidia driver this increase near of 10 degrees, a tiny task put my laptop on 50 degrees is anoying. I need work with nvidia drivers because I need CUDA. I tray bumblebee and nothing happens.
Im using ubuntu 14.04, nvidia drivers 355, kenel 3.16.0-49 x86_64.
Maybe there are some place where I can send info about this trouble? May be on Xorg, or Ubuntu or Nvidia?

Comment: Well, by definition, as the problem does not happen with the open source driver, it is a problem with the Nvidia driver. File a bug report with Nvidia https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/522835/if-you-have-a-problem-please-read-this-first/  (Note - In my experience, Nvidia support is somewhat limited and they tend to close or ignore some bugs, YMMV)